# MVC, passport.js and verifying if user is authenticad and then redirect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

How are you all?

This time I got stuck hard.

I'm studying MVC and trying to implement an auth with passport.js. Everything went perfectly until realize that everyone, authenticated or not, can access my routes if they know the url.

Searching a bit, I found a tutorial in Youtube that solve my problem, but It doesn't use MVC and I've tried on my own, but got a strange problem:

When I try to access `/dashboard`, even logged, I got redirected to `/`. Can you guys give me a light to what I'm doing wrong?

The tutorial is : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBvmnHTQIPY&t=1545s

Thanks in advance!

my routes>login.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const loginController = require('../controllers/login');
const isLogged = require('../controllers/auth');


// @desc    Login/Landing page
// @route   GET /
router.get('/', isLogged.isLogged.ensureGuest, loginController.getLogin);

module.exports = router;
```

my controllers>auth.js

```
const passport = require('passport');


exports.getAuthGoogle = passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] });
exports.getAuthGoogleCallback = passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' });
exports.getAuthGoogleCallbackRedirect = (req, res, next) => { res.redirect('/dashboard') }

exports.getLogout = (req, res, next) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/')
}

exports.isLogged = {
    ensureAuth: (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next()
        } else {
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    },
    ensureGuest: (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.redirect('/')
        } else {
            return next()
        }
    }
}
```

my routes>dashboard.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const dashboardController = require('../controllers/dashboard');
const isLogged = require('../controllers/auth');

// @desc    Dashboard
// @route   GET /dashboard
router.get('/', isLogged.isLogged.ensureAuth, dashboardController.getDashboard);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to cut lean the isLogged redundancy, I just changed the line to this:

`const { isLogged } = require('../controllers/auth');`

At my entry point (app.js), I've initialized my Session middleware before the passport. **And you should do this.**

```
// Session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'process.env.SESSION_SECRET',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}))

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

And the, the stupid thing that was looping me back to `/` inside auth.js

```
exports.isLogged = {
    ensureAuth: (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next()
        } else {
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    },
    ensureGuest: (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.redirect('/dashboard')
        } else {
            return next()
        }
    }
```

The ensureGuest was running inside `/`. If req.isAuthenticated return TRUE, I should get redirected to `/dashboard` and not to `/` like was before.

I've learned a lot fixing my own error and now I know how to use routes properly!